# Adding figure description to the bottom of several subplots in Matplotlib

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, plot

I would like to add a figure description to the bottom of my group of subplots. Is there a built in way to do this or do I have to keep messing with `text()` to get it placed correctly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will put the label centered and 15 pixels above the bottom of the figure.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.transforms as mtrans

fig, ax = plt.subplots(2, 2)
trans = mtrans.blended_transform_factory(fig.transFigure,
                                         mtrans.IdentityTransform())

txt = fig.text(.5, 15, "total label", ha='center')
txt.set_transform(trans)
```

[image]

See http://matplotlib.org/users/transforms_tutorial.html for more on how to work with transforms.